# Convergence in $(C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I have come across the following past exam question but I'm not sure of how to sure if these converges or not.. Any help would be greatly appreciated

$$x_n(t)= \frac{nt^2}{1+ nt} \in (C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$$

Comment: As a first step, can you see whether $x_n$ pointwise converges or not?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear that $(x_n)$ converges pointwise to the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=t$ on $[0,1]$ and let $$g(t)=|x_n(t)-t|=\frac{t}{1+nt}$$
and since
$$g'(t)=\frac{1}{(1+nt)^2}\geq 0\quad\forall t\in[0,1]$$
then $g$ is increasing and hence
$$||x_n-f||_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x_n(t)-t|=g(1)=\frac{1}{1+n}\to0$$
which prove the convergence uniform of $(x_n)$ to $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges pointwise to $x(t) = t$.  Consider
$$
|x_n(t) - t| = \left\lvert -\frac{t}{1+nt} \right\rvert = \frac{t}{1+nt}.
$$
Then use one-dimensional calculus to find the maximum value over $[0,1]$ of this for each $n$.  What pops out is something that goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Or you can just use algebra precalculus to show this is bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. There is no need to compute the exact maximum.